# Query output "cuts" short - Data output limited

Tags: settings, ampps

I'm using Ampps and my MYSQL queries aren't taking long to get results, but the data cuts short at the same character count on each foreach loop output.  I'm ASSUMING there are settings that are limiting the output.  Can anyone provide what settings I can adjust to get my full results?...or am I down the wrong lane?

Been google-ing and searching on here....but not getting anywhere with it.

ty in advance!! :)

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being due to my group_concat default limit.

I went to phpmyadmin. Ran sql query to set global group_concat to larger length with this command:

SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=4294967295;

from SO users Bill & Justin on this question:

[Group Concat Results Cut Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791505/group-concat-results-cut-off)